# Pandas Dataframe ordering and sorting of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if someone knows a good way on how to sort a pandas dataframe in the following way:

a) I have the following randomly sorted data with an id that appears multiple times and a label that is either 0 or 1:

```
id | label
------ | ------ 
1 | 1
1 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 1
2 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
```

I would like to sort the labels in ascending order and then also sort the id's in ascending order, but not grouped, so like this:

```
id | label
------ | ------ 
1 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sort by id and label, then use cumcount to create an index representing 1,2,3 groups, then sort on index and by labels.

```
df_out = df.sort_values(by=['id','label'])\
  .set_index(df.groupby('id').cumcount())\
  .sort_index()\
  .sort_values(by='label')
```

Output:

```
   id  label
0   1      0
0   2      0
0   3      0
1   1      0
1   2      0
1   3      0
2   3      0
2   1      1
2   2      1
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much! You are awesome.

Comment: I knew it was definitely related to cumcount. I tried but failed. This is fantastic using sort_index.

Comment: Thank you.  I recognized the pattern in OP's results.  To me this is why people need to explain their logic and put sample inputs with expected outputs.